# Elegant Number Button not showing in Android Studio XML preview

Tags: xml, android-studio

As what the title says the elegant number button is not showing in my XML preview. 
I have added and successfully synced in my gradle app

```
    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.3'
```

And have this XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Customer.ProductDetailsActivity"
        tools:replace="android:theme">

        <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
            android:id="@+id/elegantNumberButton_quantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:initialNumber="1"
            app:finalNumber="10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView_labelquantity"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView_labelquantity"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_labelquantity"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp">
        </com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But still the elegant number button is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. **Rebuilding The Project** fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

**it is work but the background is White.**

add this line: `app:backGroundColor="#ffffff" app:textColor="#000000" app:textSize="8sp"`

Comment: thanks @Ahmed, it's really helped me

Answer (score 0):

For this you should try rebuilding the project. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `jcenter()` as a repository in the application *build.gradle* file.
It seems that this dependency is only hosted on `jcenter()` and nowhere else.

Source - [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button/lib/1.0.3#:~:text=Note%3A%20this%20artifact,jcenter.bintray.com/](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button/lib/1.0.3#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20this%20artifact,jcenter.bintray.com/))